# Nested query with spring data jpa and eclipselink

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with spring ,spring data jpa ,and eclipselink i am using a Repository to define my queries , i have a nested query , its working in mysql directly but not in my Repository

```
    @Query("Select don from Donnee don where don.RowNumber in  "
            + "(Select DISTINCT(do.RowNumber) from Donnee do"  
            + " WHERE char_length(do.valeur) > 14 and Substring(do.valeur, 7, 4) = ?1 )" )
    public List<Donnee> DonnesparDate(String date);
```

i get this error : [101, 164] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

any help please

Comment: Did you try to use JPAs LENGTH() function instead of char_length ?

Answer (score 0):

try with entity manager

```
String query = "Select don from Donnee don where don.RowNumber in  "
        + "(Select DISTINCT(do.RowNumber) from Donnee do"  
        + " WHERE char_length(do.valeur) > 14 and Substring(do.valeur, 7, 4) = ?1 )";

EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
```

Query result = em.createQuery(query);
List results = result.getResultList();

and also autowire EntityManager like this : `@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;`